# Pseudo first class functions in Java?

Tags: java, closures, implementation, lambda

Below I have a rough implementation of testing a list lambda functions on an integer in Python.  I know Java currently doesn't support closures or lambdas (yet), but I'm curious, is this remotely possible in Java?

```
pos = [lambda x : x > 0, "pos"]
even = [lambda x : x % 2 == 0, "even"]
small = [lambda x : x < 100, "small"]

def pass_test(x, tests):
    if (len(tests) == 0): return []
    else:
        if (tests[0][0](x)): return [tests[0][1]] + pass_test(x, tests[1:])
        else: return pass_test(x, tests[1:])
```

Comment: The closest thing is really an anonymous implementation of an interface or abstract class.

Comment: Are you simply looking how you would write the code in Java using methods in place of lamda functions?

Comment: As @bowenl2 said, you would need smth like: ```public interface Function { String do(int x); }``` And then you can create lots of anonymous inner classes for each function instance.

Comment: There should be lambdas (concise anonymous inner classes) in Java SE 8. Although it'll still be a nominative typed language, so you'll still need to declare a type. / Enums give a merely semi-verbose way of implementing the same type in a number of stateless ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, along the lines of:

```
interface Predicate<A> {
    boolean eval(A argument);
}

Predicate<Integer> gt0 = new Predicate<Integer>() {
    boolean eval(Integer arg) {
        return arg > 0;
    }
};
```

You see, this is a bit verbose, but it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, python function could be mapped to Java like this:

```
public interface Function { 
    String do(int x); 
}

// ...
Function pos = new Function(){
    public String do(int x) {
        return (x > 0) ? "pos" : "";
    }
}
Function even = new Function(){
    public String do(int x) {
        return (x % 2 == 0) ? "even" : "";
    }
}
Function small = new Function(){
    public String do(int x) {
        return (x < 100) ? "small" : "";
    }
}

// ...
```

As you see, you'd need a lot more code to do the same simple thing in Java.